# how can I sniff Bluetooth traffic coming from my and another device?

Tags: networking, android, bluetooth, debug, sniffing

I am trying to debug some Bluetooth traffic. I have one windows computer that I have full access too, I have an android phone, and I have a wireless hardware device. I want to know if there is a way to sniff the bluetooth traffic coming from the windows computer and from the android phone, which are both sending to the wireless hardware device.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the LogCat app on your android device, or you can use the LogCat function in the Android SDK if you connect your android device to a computer.

Wireshark has no support for bluetooth on Windows, but you could boot a live version of linux to get that functionality.

I would personally suggest LogCat, It is very detailed.